# Convert date keeps failing dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii

Tags: php, date

I'm desperately looking to convert my date to Y-m-d H:i
My date: 19/06/2014 09:30

I tried this:

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateValue)
    ->format('Y-m-d');
```

But this will give the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

I tried with the Procedural style, yet that doesn't work.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime(dateValue));
```

I tried some other stuff and nothing seems to work. Can't even convert it to unix.
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to account for the time when using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` even if you don't want it when you format the date later:

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dateValue)->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/u7KR4Q)

Comment: Gee, how did you know? ;)

Comment: Oh, AND a demo, sweetening the pot eh? Oh and how did I know(?)... I just know ;-)